# Using data frame values to select columns of a different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm relatively new in R so excuse me if I'm not even posting this question the right way.

I have a matrix generated from combination function.

```
double_expression_combinations <- combn(marker_column_vector,2)
```

This matrix has x columns and 2 rows. Each column has 2 rows with numbers that will be used to represent column numbers in my main data frame named `initial`. These columns numbers are combinations of columns to be tested. The `initial` data frame is 27 columns (thousands of rows) with values of 1 and 0. The test consists in using the 2 numbers given by `double_expression_combinations` as column numbers to use from `initial`. The test consists in adding each row of those 2 columns and counting how many times the sum is equal to 2.

I believe I'm able to come up with the counting part, I just don't know how to use the data from the `double_expression_combinations` data frame to select columns to test from the "initial" data frame.

*Edited to fix corrections made by commenters*

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [mcve], then edit your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `combn` produces a matrix, not a data.frame, which will make a rather large difference for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using R it's important to keep your terminology precise. `double_expression_combinations` is not a dataframe but rather a `matrix`. It's easy to loop over columns in a matrix with `apply`. I'm a bit unclear about the exact test,  but this might succeed:

```
 apply( double_expression_combinations, 2,  # the 2 selects each column in turn
          function(cols){ sum( initial[ , cols[1] ] + initial[ , cols[2] ] == 2) } )
```

Both the '+' and '==' operators are vectorised so no additional loop is needed inside the call to `sum`.

Comment: You got it! Thank you. I will also need to do the same but with combinations of 3 as in a triple_expression_combinations matrix. If I do apply( triple_expression_combinations, 2, function(cols){ sum( initial[ , cols[1] ] + initial[ , cols[2] ] + initial[ , cols[3] ] == 3) } ) Should work right? @42-